# Create my own custom keyboard with my own images

Tags: android, facebook, keyboard, whatsapp, ime

On Android, I need to create my own IME which lets users to choose an image and send it right away to the already open WhatsApp, Email, Facebook, etc window,
without showing any extra chooser (cause we're already working with the contact we wnat to send the image to).

To have a better idea, it should work as an emoji keyboard but using my own images, similar to the Ikea emoticons app.

I've already tried with Intent, but couldn't find a way to point it to the already active contact window.

Here's the code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: So, you've already created the custom keyboard?

Comment: Yep, key point is how to use my own IME to let users to choose and send images to the window they're working (a contact whatsapp window). Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, the title is a bit misleading. Can you show us the code that you have that is failing?

Comment: Notice it's hardcoded to whatsapp but the idea is, no matter the app you're working with, after choosing the IME, you could pick and image and send it right away to the contact. This code works ok, however whatsapp force me to choose a contact/group to send the picked image to.

Comment: How are you detecting the window in which the user is working??

Comment: have you find the solution for this?